# Spline curves using achartengine with cubic line chart doesnt pass through all points

Tags: android, achartengine, cubic-spline

I am using achartengine with cubic line chart, but it doesnt seem to work. The cubic line chart doesnt pass through all the points in the series. In this example, the graph is far away from the points. What am I doing wrong, or is this an actual issue with achartengine?

[image: cubiclinechart]

Code:

```
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset series = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

    XYValueSeries newTicketSeries = new XYValueSeries("New Tickets");
    newTicketSeries.add(1, 14);
    newTicketSeries.add( 2, 12);
    newTicketSeries.add(3, 18);
    newTicketSeries.add( 4, 5);
    newTicketSeries.add( 5, 10);
    series.addSeries(newTicketSeries);
    XYValueSeries fixedTicketSeries = new XYValueSeries("Fixed Tickets");
    fixedTicketSeries.add( 1, 15);
    fixedTicketSeries.add( 2, 5);
    fixedTicketSeries.add( 3, 15);
    fixedTicketSeries.add(4, 5);
    fixedTicketSeries.add(5, 15);
    series.addSeries(fixedTicketSeries);

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();

    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(56);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(50);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(55);
    renderer.setZoomEnabled(true, false);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);

    renderer.setRange(new double[]{0, 10, 0, 20});

    //renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
    XYSeriesRenderer newTicketRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    newTicketRenderer.setColor(Color.argb(250, 0, 210, 250));
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(newTicketRenderer);
    XYSeriesRenderer fixedTicketRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    fixedTicketRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
    fixedTicketRenderer.setLineWidth(10);

    fixedTicketRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);

    fixedTicketRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    renderer.addSeriesRenderer(fixedTicketRenderer);

    renderer.setPointSize(40);
    renderer.setXLabels(0);
    renderer.setYLabels(0);
    newTicketRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    newTicketRenderer.setChartValuesTextSize(30);
    renderer.setShowGrid(false);
    renderer.setShowLegend(true);
    renderer.setShowLabels(false);
    renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.argb(0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01)); 

    //renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);

    GraphicalView chartView;



    String[] types = new String[] { BarChart.TYPE, CubicLineChart.TYPE};

    chartView = ChartFactory.getCombinedXYChartView(getActivity(), series, renderer, types);
```

Comment: What version of ACE are you using?

Comment: Latest. 1.1.0. Also, the demo suffers from the same bug. If you go to AChartEngine demo and then select Combined temperature. The same effect can be seen on the orange line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug, indeed. I checked in a fix in the SVN. You can download a version including this fix [here](https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.2.0/).

Comment: Oh thanks! How do I pass the types to getCombinedXYChartView in the new version? The new version result in compile errors using types like this: new String[] { BarChart.TYPE, CubicLineChart.TYPE};

Comment: See this example: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/CombinedTemperatureChart.java

Comment: Just discovered that its not 100% correct. The graph now passes through all points, but some points are not positioned correctly(which they were before). Also the graph seems to be less smooth than expected.